# Why can't the Lost Boys fly?

Tags: peter-pan, j-m-barrie

In Peter Pan, all you need to do to fly is think of a wonderful thought, any happy little thought. All it takes is faith and trust ohh and there's dust. Pixie dust.

Why then can't the Lost Boys fly? They have fun all day and they are around TinkerBell enough to get plenty of pixie dust... do they just choose not to fly?

Comment: Do you have a reference which says they can't? I always assumed they could - I remember being annoyed because the film Hook showed them as not flying.

Comment: No work I've read or seen showed them flying.

Comment: @DanielRoseman some of those lost boys were too.... er *stout* to fly.

Comment: I've been going through the text of the first book.  I could have sworn I remembered the Lost Boys flying, but it looks like once they get to Neverland, not even the newcomers fly anymore.  I think Jeff has about the best explanation you're going to find.  Tink is quite jealous, and Peter had to grab her to get pixie dust so they could fly from London to Neverland, so it's likely she doesn't share willingly.

Comment: LOL --  When I read this question's title, I promptly went digging for my copy of 'The Lost Boys'; I thought I remembered the Vampires flying off the bridge... Then I read the actual question.. DOH! Noticing the tags might have helped, too :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They can (and do) in the broadway version — the penultimate scene has them arrive in the window at the Darling residence for a rousing chorus of "I *will* grow up." Since the only way to and from Neverland is flight, it would follow that they were able to fly.

For that matter, they are fully capable in **Hook** as well, provided that they obtain the magical dust. Recall the finding of marbles in one of the final scenes — fairy dust was included in the bag which lead to a rather elderly lost "boy" taking flight.

My guess is that it is a supply issue. Tinkerbell and her folk are simply unable to provide sufficient dust to lift the entire group off of the ground continuously, so the material is rationed. Peter's special relationship with Tinkerbell specifically likely keeps him in constant supply, but the others do not have this boon.

Answer (score 17):

This is from the actual novel by J.M. Barrie, near the end, when the Lost Boys have been adopted by the Darlings:

"Of course all the boys went to school; and most of them got into Class III, but Slightly was put first into Class IV and then into Class V. Class I is the top class. Before they had attended school a week they saw what goats they had been not to remain on the island; but it was too late now, and soon they settled down to being as ordinary as you or me or Jenkins minor [the younger Jenkins]. It is sad to have to say that the power to fly gradually left them. At first Nana tied their feet to the bed-posts so that they should not fly away in the night; and one of their diversions by day was to pretend to fall off buses [the English double-deckers]; but by and by they ceased to tug at their bonds in bed, and found that they hurt themselves when they let go of the bus. In time they could not even fly after their hats. Want of practice, they called it; but what it really meant was that they no longer believed."

So yes, the Lost Boys could fly.

Answer (score 3):

The lost boys are never seen to fly, even when it would make sense (or be very fun) so we must assume they are incapable.

The most likely reason is that Tinkerbell is unwilling to give them pixie dust.  Peter is the only one who gets it, and he's decided that's the way it should be - he's the leader.

Children are like this - when there is a large group with an obvious leader, it simply isn't questioned that the leader gets the cool stuff.  They get the Green Ranger toys (showing my age there, I think), they get the 'good' cars, and they get the flying ability.

Answer (score 0):

It was a gift to Peter from the fairy queen so he could go home. However, his mum had shut Peter's window and given birth to a replacement baby, so Peter returned to Neverland. The Lost Boys weren't given the option to go home.